# JQuery replace text dynamically

Tags: javascript, array, text

Estoy intentando crear una galleria donde los textos cambien cuando el usuario hace clic en la barra rosa que ahora muestra el texto: "Previus Text" / "Post Text", respectivamente.

Aqui el codigo:
https://jsfiddle.net/mayte_labarga/rczjrova/2/

Lo que no consigo de ninguna manera es que aparezcan todos los textos que tengo en mi arreglo. Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas.

Comment: Hola mayte, bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Como el nombre indica, el idioma de este sitio es el español. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta. También te recomiendo que completes el [tour] y que leas [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta (por ejemplo, incluyendo el código directamente en la pregunta en lugar de enlazando a sitios externos)

Comment: el editor de textos de aquí también tiene la opción de agregar el código para evitar que en algún futuro la liga que pusiste legara a desaparecer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He visto dos errores en el código:

- Los eventos click los tienes que poner a los `<a>`, y
- en la función que cambiaba el nombre has puesto el nombre del array mal.

Te dejo el código actualizado (también en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rczjrova/14/)):

```js
var textPrev = document.getElementsByClassName("txtPrev");
var textPost = document.getElementsByClassName("txtPost");
var siguiente = document.getElementsByClassName("next");
var antes = document.getElementsByClassName("prev");

var textoPre =new Array(9);
textoPre[0]="Condor Films";
textoPre[1]="Stories AG";
textoPre[2]="Boutiq AG";
textoPre[3]="Leguan Produktions";
textoPre[4]="Condor Films";
textoPre[5]="Stories AG";
textoPre[6]="Boutiq AG";
textoPre[7]="Leguan Produktions";
textoPre[8]="Boutiq AG";

var numFirma=8;
var firma =0;
if(firma === 0){
$(textPost).text(textoPre[firma]);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
'use strict';  

$(siguiente).click(function(){
 if(firma<numFirma){
  $(textPrev).text(textoPre[firma]);
  firma= firma+1
  $(textPost).text(textoPre[firma]);
  $("#firma").text(firma);
 }
else{
 alert("Es ist die Letztes Bild");
  } 
}); 

$(antes).click(function(){  
  
 if(firma>0){
  $(textPost).text(textoPre[firma]);
 firma= firma-1
 $(textPrev).text(textoPre[firma]);
$("#firma").text(firma);
}else{
    alert("Es ist die Erste Bild");
  }  
});    
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  /*text-align: left;*/
  /*z-index: 1000;*/
  /* -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);*/
  /* transform: translateY(-50%);*/
}

nav a.prev {
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

nav a.next {
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

nav a svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-fillslide .icon-wrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
  padding: 65px 10px;
  /*distancia entre ellos*/
  background: #455C7B;
  /*#b68dbe*/
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/*barra blanca*/

.nav-fillslide .icon-wrap::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: #7095C7;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s 0.3s;
}

.nav-fillslide a.prev .icon-wrap::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.nav-fillslide a.next .icon-wrap::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.nav-fillslide div {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 115px;
  background: #A75265;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.nav-fillslide a.prev div {
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 150px 20px 70px;
  /*text-align: right;*/
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.nav-fillslide a.next div {
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px 70px 20px 150px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.nav-fillslide h3 {
  margin: 10px 0 0 -30px;
  padding: 8px 50px 10px 15px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", "monospace";
}

.nav-fillslide a:hover .icon-wrap::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.nav-fillslide a:hover div {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <nav class="nav-fillslide">
  <a class="prev" href="#">
   <span class="icon-wrap"><svg class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 64 64"><use xlink:href="#arrow-left-4"></use></svg></span>
    <section class="oculto"> </section>
     <div class="prevImagen">     
      <h3 class="txtPrev"> Previus Text</h3>
     </div>
     
  </a>
         
  <a class="next" href="#">
     <span class="icon-wrap"><svg class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 64 64"><use xlink:href="#arrow-right-4"></use></svg></span>
           <div class="carruselImg">
      <h3 class="txtPost">Post-Text</h3>
     </div>
    </a>
 <span id="firma"></span>
 </nav> <!-- Final de la navegacion -->
```

Comment: Hola Jorge, he editado tu pregunta para traer el código a la propia respuesta. Te recomiendo que leas [answer] y que evites contestar preguntas que son de baja calidad o no cumplen con el formato del sitio.

Comment: Hola Jorge. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Tienes razon. De tantos intentos no he escrito bien el nombre del arreglo. Ahora mismo lo corrijo. Te podria hacer una pregunta? Tienes idea de porque no puedo ver todos los textos de mi arreglo cada vez que se hace clic. Mil mil gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Hola @maytelabarga he editado la respuesta.

Comment: mil gracias, Jorge